# How to include a library on bintray in Scala Maven project

Tags: scala, maven

I'm making a project in Scala (2.11), using Maven as my build tool. I'd like to use [this library](https://github.com/cakesolutions/scala-kafka-client), but I can't get it to work.

I have a minimal (2 files) example repository here: https://github.com/evertheylen/scala-maven-bintray-example

I added two dependencies, [`kafka`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.11) and [`scala-kafka-client`](https://bintray.com/cakesolutions/maven/scala-kafka-client). Both times I followed the instructions on their respective websites, but the last one (from bintray) is giving me problems. I would like the repository to be defined [in the project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html), and not in my personal `settings.xml` (though I did try that and it didn't work).

The error given to me by `mvn package exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=be.evertheylen.SampleApplication` is:

```
[ERROR] .../src/main/scala/SampleApplication.scala:3: error: not found: object cakesolutions
[ERROR] import cakesolutions.kafka.KafkaProducer
[ERROR]        ^
[ERROR] .../src/main/scala/SampleApplication.scala:4: error: not found: object cakesolutions
[ERROR] import cakesolutions.kafka.KafkaProducer.Conf
[ERROR]        ^
[ERROR] two errors found
```

Although `mvn dependency:list` does in fact list the library:

```
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
...
[INFO]    net.cakesolutions:scala-kafka-client_2.11:pom:0.10.0.0-RC2:compile
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `<type>pom</type>` from the dependency declaration in your pom.xml.

Comment: Please explain how this helps and why removing <type>pom</type> will work. I tried this and it did not help.

Comment: Using type=pom in the dependency declaration only pulls down transitive dependencies, that is jar dependencies defined as dependencies in the pom.

`<dependency>
`    <groupId>net.cakesolutions</groupId>
`    <artifactId>scala-kafka-client_2.11</artifactId>
`    <version>0.10.0.0-RC2</version>
` </dependency>

Comment: Well it seems to be working me though, I'm going to try using this in the actual project I need it for, and if it works I'll accept the answer. Perhaps you  could also edit your answer to incorporate the explanation.